# How to return items from my CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, scrapy, yield-return

I want to start scraping from one page and traverse to 100s of page using next url, which i have written in following code. I need to go to another link  in that crawling and extract data and store in the items. I can easily print all the items data to be exported but not able to return from the function as desired.

```
class UserLoginCrawl(CrawlSpider):
name = "mylogin"
allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
login_page = "www.example.com/user"

start_urls = ["www.example.com/profile?page=0"]
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(
    allow = ('/profile\?page=\d+'),
    restrict_xpaths = ('//li[@class="pager-next"]',),canonicalize=False ),
              callback = 'parse_page',
              follow=True),]
# ulists = []

def parse_page(self, response):
    self.log ('XYZ, Started Crawling %s' %response.url)
    items = response.xpath("//div[@id='profile']/div")
    for temp in items:
        userurl = 'www.example.com'+temp.xpath("./div[@class='name']/a/@href").extract()[0]
        yield Request(url=userurl,callback=self.parse_profile_page)
    self.log ('XYZ, Finished Crawling %s' %response.url)
    # return self.ulists

def parse_profile_page(self, response):
    usritem = PostUsers()
    self.log ('XYZ, Started Crawling user Profile %s' %response.url)
    usritem["userlink"] = response.url
    usritem["fullname"] = response.xpath("//h1[@id='page-title']/text()").extract()
    relative_url = response.xpath("//div[@id='nav-content']/ul/li[2]/a/@href").extract()[0]
    usritem["postlink"] = 'www.example.com'+relative_url
    usritem["history"] = response.xpath("//div[@id='user_user_full_group_profile_main']/dl/dd[1]/text()").extract()
    # self.ulists.append(usritem)
    print usritem
    # return usritem
```

Comment: I want to export the four fields in the csv form using "scrapy crawl mylogin -t csv -o mylist.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Use `yield usritem` at the end of your parse method.

See the second example of [Spider Examples](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/spiders.html#spider-example)

Comment: thanks for you idea. But i followed the best way using meta tag       request = Request(userurl,callback=self.parse_profile_page)
request.meta['usritem'] = usritem and profile_page returning usritem